# Python Detect numbers in string by a list of sample

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def value(c):

if any(c.isdigit() for c in value):
  print("1")
else:
  print("0")


value = 'www.test.com' #list of sample
value = 'www.123.com'
value = 'www.test.com'
```

How to detect numbers in string by a list of sample?

i have to compile in 1 time to get the output of a list of samples, is there any method to modify my code in the python file to loop for a list of "value" instead of only 1? beside writing the code in python shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> value = 'www.test.com'
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
False
>>> value = 'www.123.com'
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
True
>>> value = 'www.tes$%%^^^t.com'
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
False
```

Or you can write it this way:

```
>>> value = 'www.123.com'
>>> containsdigit = any(c.isdigit() for c in value)
>>> if containsdigit:
...     print("1")
... else:
...     print("0")
... 
1
```

**Update:** Lets assume the function def value(c) takes a list as parameter. Then i can define the function this way.

```
def value(c):
    for b in c:
        containsdigit = any(a.isdigit() for a in b)
        if containsdigit:
            print("The result of : "+ b + " is 1")
        else:
            print("The result of : " + b +" is 0")
```

from my console i can declare a list c as `c =['www.123.com','www.abc.com','www.dfd#$%%.com']`

i can now pass c to my function as shown below:

```
value(c)

output
The result of : www.123.com is 1
The result of : www.abc.com is 0
The result of : www.dfd#$%%.com is 0
```

Comment: i have to compile in 1 time to get the output of a list of samples, is there any method to modify my code in the python file? beside writing the code in python shell.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

No quite sure whether I got the question correctly, but if you want to check whether or not there are certain characters in your string, use regular expressions:

```
import re
if re.search("1","www.test1.com")!=None:
    print("has number")
else:
    print("has no number")
```

In a function:

```
values = "01234" # numbers 0,1,2,3,4
# values= "\d" # all digits
def values_in_string(s, values):
  return(re.search(values,s)!=None)
```